# What's the term for a line of dialog that is repeated later in a different context, especially as a clever retort?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the term for a line of dialog that is repeated later in a different context?

Christopher Nolan seems to be fond of these lines. In *Batman Begins*, Ra's first says:

> Always mind your surroundings

And then in the climax Batman says

> You never learned to mind your surroundings.

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, Bane first says:

> Then, you have my permission to die

as he's breaking Batman, and later Batman claps back with

> Then, you have my permission to die.

Same line, different contexts, often as witty comebacks.

I've thought of a couple of possibilities I've heard of, none of which works quite well:

- Callbacks seem to be a reference to a previous gag, rather than an exact quote.
- Comebacks and clapbacks can be any kinds of clever retorts, not necessarily the use of your opponent's words against themselves

Comment: I think a callback can be anything, including a line of dialog.

Comment: I don't know how authoritative [this author is](https://www.septembercfawkes.com/2019/10/writing-callbacks.html), but the article discusses callbacks as being exactly this.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(comedy)) also uses the phrase *internal allusion* but that's even more general (and not a single word).

Comment: @StuartF I had no idea even an actual writer wasn't aware of that. If there's literally nothing better, I guess *callback* has to do.

Comment: Does this depend on the context being different? I ask because repeating lines in the same context is one of the oldest devices known to literature and after roughly 5,000 years is still in use today.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Repetition alone is meaningless without a rhetorical force. The examples I showed above are all about when the hero uses the villain's words against themselves. "See, you told me this, how about I clap back at you with your own words?"

Comment: Thanks and 'repetition alone is meaningless without a rhetorical force' seems to deny, for instance, emphasis. 'Come-back' features two ways in ordinary English but neither in this context and 'clap-back' simply doesn't. 'Call-back' has a place, usually when a candidate is called back for a further interview or test, and even in theatre I believe a 'call-back' would more likely refer to another audition that reference back to a previous episode…